# how to skip the "install page" for a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

thank you for your time first.
I have a very simple question here,but I can't figure it out for an entire day.
I built an facebook app which just post a message to wall,the problem is it requires user install the app first then request permission,that means 2 clicks,I don't like.

I saw somebody merged the 2 steps into 1,how did he get it?
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-graph-api-post-to-wall/index2.html
And this one is mine
http://2.youpiaoma.com/fb_api/post2wall.html

Here is the snap of the install page
2.youpiaoma.com/a.JPG

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using the new **enhanced auth dialog** in your app, and for some reason it is not honoring the `&perms=publish_stream` parameter.  Since the blog is older, some of the code is out of date with the more current ways of doing things.

I think you may benefit from using the new feed dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

But if you want to continue using the old code, I would suggest the following changes:

- you can use the FB.login() call instead of building the string yourself.  That way the API is responsible for making the login box correct.
- specify a channelUrl in your FB.init() call too. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Comment: Thanks you,DMCS  I tried the new scripts you posted,just replace "FB.ui" with "FB.api" and add a "message" field as I want post something without interface,but unfortunately,it return "undefined response"   I'm newbie to facebook and it seems a bit knotty,anyway,your answer is helpful and make me know more about it.

Comment: Post a link to your code, it might be helpful to see what you're doing.  Also ensure your app id you're using has the website's url correctly identified.